# 1000 max shards reached. I would like to increase or clear exisitng and start again. I have 5 servers I am monitoring

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, wazuh

I tried to increase the shards with this...but to no avail.

```
 curl -XPUT 'http://206.189.196.214:9200/_cluster/settings -H 'Content-type: application/json' --data-binary $'{"transient":{"cluster.max_shards_per_node":5100}}'`
```

I have a typo in the above ... it returned the below error:

> "error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"invalid
> version format: -H CONTENT-TYPE:
> HTTP/1.1"}],"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"invalid
> version format: -H CONTENT-TYPE: HTTP/1.1"},"status":400}curl: (3)
> [globbing] nested brace in column 44

Please advise. Thoughts. Elasticsearch is running, Zabbix is running, logstash is running, all seems happy but reached a limit on 1000/1000 shards.

Answer (score 1):

It would be a better option if you set this limit into your `elasticserch.yml` file. Because if you restart your cluster you will lose these configs. But your request would be something like this:

```
curl -XPUT "http://elasticsearch_host:9200/_cluster/settings" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
{
  "transient": {
    "cluster.routing.allocation.total_shards_per_node": 5100
  }
}'
```

Comment: this setting would be lost after a cluster restart - that's what `transient` means